# SSIS Subtracting from 2 sources

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I currently have two Excel sources. I'm hoping to subtract a count of rows from one Excel source (SourceA) with a row value from the other excel source (SourceB). 
I've used a conditional split on each to specify which rows I want to use. SourceA returns one row which is what I wanted. Source B returns a number of rows which is what I expected.

From the SourceA data flow, I've now added an aggregate transformation to count the number of rows .

I then use a Union All, a data conversion transformation and then a Derived Column transformation. In this Derived Column transformation, I use the column from SourceB - the aggregate count of SourceA.

Then I link it to a SQL Server Destination and configure the mappings. I run the data flow and everything works. However, when I look at the results, it only gives me a NULL value (it did not calculate it for me).

How can I achieve this subtraction of a row value and an aggregate count?

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate transformation is asynchronous meaning that it won't produce an output for each input row. You probably need a Merge Join instead of a Union. You may want to consider using a variable to hold the aggregated value as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you are looking by following:

1) Get the Row count From Source A and Source B by creating variable1 and variable2.

2) You can do drag Derived column or another variable you can do the subtraction of Variable1-Variable2.

3) Map the Final variable or Derived column to the destination.